# Populating database table column with corresponding values from another table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update, syntax-error

Table 1 is 'z_scrapestorm_rentals' and table 2 is 'pcpao_cols'. They both have address columns named 'address_1_line_trunc' and 'address_one_line' respectively.

Both tables also have a column named 'web_strap', but only 'pcpao_cols' has values in this column that are not null.

**I want these values from pcpao_cols.web_strap copied into z_scrapestorm_rentals.web_strap for rows where z_scrapestorm_rentals.address_1_line_trunc matches pcpao_cols.address_one_line.**

I used a few different queries to do this, but they either appear to run successfully (no errors) without actually updating any values or I get errors.

## Method 1:

*(no errors and DBeaver says 124 rows were updated but the 'web_strap' column in z_scrapestorm_rentals table still doesn't have any values in it... I know matches exist since I can successfully query them, but I just can't seem to update the table.)*

```
UPDATE z_scrapestorm_rentals
    SET web_strap = z_scrapestorm_rentals.web_strap
    FROM pcpao_cols
    WHERE z_scrapestorm_rentals.address_1_line_trunc ILIKE pcpao_cols.address_one_line;
```

## Method 2:

*(syntax error at or near 'SELECT')*

```
UPDATE z_scrapestorm_rentals
    SELECT
        z_scrapestorm_rentals.*,
        pcpao_cols.web_strap
    FROM z_scrapestorm_rentals
LEFT JOIN pcpao_cols
ON z_scrapestorm_rentals.address_1_line_trunc = pcpao_cols.address_one_line;
```

## Method 3:

*(error: invalid reference to FROM-caluse entry for table "z_scrapestorm_rentals"...Hint: there is an entry for table "z_scrapestorm_rentals", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. Position 89)*

```
INSERT INTO z_scrapestorm_rentals (web_strap)
    SELECT web_strap
    FROM pcpao_cols
    WHERE z_scrapestorm_rentals.address_1_line_trunc ILIKE pcpao_cols.address_one_line;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I answered my own question and inserted the `web_strap` values from the other table into the target table by using the following query:

```
UPDATE z_scrapestorm_rentals
    SET web_strap = pcpao_cols.web_strap
    FROM
        pcpao_cols
    WHERE Z_scrapestorm_rentals.address_1_line_trunc 
ILIKE pcpao_cols.address_one_line
    RETURNING pcpao_cols.web_strap;
```

What was missing from my original query I detailed in my question's "method 1" was the `RETURNING` keyword.

Comment: You should accept your own answer (you can do this once the answer is 24 hours old). Accepting answers helps others know the question is resolved.

Comment: I will as soon as the site lets me. When I tried yesterday I got the message "you can accept your own answer 2 days after posting it".